# Ruby require 'rack' fails

Tags: ruby, rack, redmine, passenger

I'm trying to install redmine and I have a problem with phusion-passenger. Installer fails on dependencies saying that rack is missing. I've investigated the code to check where it looks for it, but I've found a line:

```
require 'rack'
```

that is enclosed in what seems to be rubys try-catch block.
I've already installed rack through gem install rack -v=1.0.1 . I've got no idea what to do next to resolve this issue. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo gem install rack`.

Comment: I was logged in as root. Nevertheless I did what you suggested (logged as usual user and tried installing rack with sudo) and no effect.

Comment: This is strange. Do you use bundler or something. What does `gem which rack` say?

Comment: Reinstalling passenger helped.. No idea why.